# Python script for 'ps aux' command

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, process, command

I have tried to use **subprocess.check_output()** for getting the **ps aux** command using python but it looks like not working with the large grep string.
Can anyone have any solution?

```
subprocess.check_output('ps aux | grep "bin/scrapy" | grep "option1" | grep "option2" | grep "option3" | grep "option4" | grep "option5"' , shell =True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have found the solution to achieve the output, We can use the following code snippet to find the PID as output.

Instead of using **ps aux** we can use **psutil** python library.

```
import psutil

args_list = ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        process_args_list = process.cmdline()
    except psutil._exceptions.NoSuchProcess as err:
        logger.info(f"Found error in psutil, Error: {err}")
        continue
    if all(item in process_args_list for item in args_list):
        print(process.pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet for executing commands on remote host

```py
# create ssh client

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

# add host key

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# connect to host

ssh.connect(hostname='somehost', username='someuser', password='somepass')


# Login using RSA key

# ssh.connect(hostname='somehost', username='someuser', key_filename='/home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa')

# execute command

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ps aux')

# print output

for line in stdout:
    print(line)

# close connection

ssh.close()

# Output

# $ python3 test.py
```

Comment: hi @codeaprendiz thanks for your response and valuable time, actually I am on the remote server and want to  trigger that script to there.